# Angular 5 rewrite rule when using DNS shortName for URL ( IIS 8.5)

Tags: url-rewriting, angular5, iis-8

I am using an shortname ( DNS entry) to map my angular 5 app URL.
Application is hosted in IIS  as shown in the below image,
I have mapped the path to application to a short-name called "arcm".
So the moment, I type this short-name in browser address bar, I see my default route.

[image]

But the problem is,
if I refresh it on any route, I see 404 error.
Following is my web.config file and rewrite rule,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
 <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <clear />
          <rule name="AngularJS" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="arcm/" />
          <action type="Rewrite" url="http://arcm/" appendQueryString="false"/>
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>

    </system.webServer>
        </configuration>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the following changes resolve my issue,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
 <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <clear />
        <rule name="Http Redirection" enabled="true" patternSyntax="Wildcard" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="*" negate="false" />
          <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny">
                        <add input="{HTTP}" pattern="off" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Redirect" url="http://{HTTP_HOST}{REQUEST_URI}" redirectType="Found" />
        </rule>
        <rule name="AngularJS" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url=".*" />
          <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
            <add input="{URL}" negate="true" pattern="\.axd$" />
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Rewrite" url="/" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>


    </system.webServer>
   </configuration>
```